# error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::list’

Tags: c++, stl, sqlite

I have following program named **DBAccess.h**

```
#ifndef DBAccess1_HH
#define DBAccess1_HH

#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct InOut_Schedular_Settings
{
    string inout_ID;
    string inout_FromTime; 
    string inout_ToTime;
    string inout_InOutMode;
};

class sqliteDB {

    public:
        int rc;
        char *zErrMsg;
        sqlite3 *db;
        const char *sql;
        sqlite3_stmt * stmt;

const char* InOut_Schedular_Settings(const char* buffer1,const char* buffer2, const char* buffer3)
{
        //====SOME CODE TO ACCESS SQLITE DATABASE====//
}


231    list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> GET_InOut_Schedular_Settings(const char* buffer1)
232     {

238    list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> InOut_Schedular_Settings_list;

       int rc = sqlite3_open("/DBsqlite3/empdbv3.db", &db);

       sql = "SELECT * FROM InOutTimeM WHERE ID= @ID;";

       rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

       int Code_x1 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(stmt, "@ID");

       if(sqlite3_step(stmt)==SQLITE_ROW) {

           int column = sqlite3_column_count(stmt);

           for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
           {
               std::string A = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)));
               std::string B = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)));
               std::string C = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)));
               std::string D = std::string(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)));

288            InOut_Schedular_Settings info; //Creating list object "info"
289            info.inout_ID = A;
290            info.inout_FromTime = B;
291            info.inout_ToTime = C;
292            info.inout_InOutMode = D;             

294            cout<<"Preparing to push data into List"<<endl;
295            InOut_Schedular_Settings_list.push_back(info);
               cout<<"Data was pushed successfully"<<endl;
           }

       }
       else {
            cout<<"\nERROR while fetching record from the InOutTimeM table[ " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << " ]" << endl;
       }

       sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
       sqlite3_close(db);

       return InOut_Schedular_Settings_list;

   }
```

Program where I called this DBAccess.h is as follows **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "DBAccess.h"
using namespace std ;

int main()
{
    sqliteDB object1;

    const char* value1= "2";

    object1.GET_InOut_Schedular_Settings(value1);

    cout << "\n\nAll the statement were executed properly\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program when compiled gives following error:

```
DBAccess.h:231:30: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::list’
 list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> GET_InOut_Schedular_Settings(const char* buffer1)
                          ^
DBAccess.h:231:30: error:   expected a type, got ‘sqliteDB::InOut_Schedular_Settings’
DBAccess.h:231:30: error: template argument 2 is invalid
DBAccess.h: In member function ‘int sqliteDB::GET_InOut_Schedular_Settings(const char*)’:
    DBAccess.h:238:31: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::list’
  list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> InOut_Schedular_Settings_list;
                           ^
DBAccess.h:238:31: error:   expected a type, got ‘sqliteDB::InOut_Schedular_Settings’
DBAccess.h:238:31: error: template argument 2 is invalid
DBAccess.h:238:62: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
 list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> InOut_Schedular_Settings_list;
                                                          ^
DBAccess.h:288:29: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘info’
InOut_Schedular_Settings info; //Creating list object "info"
                         ^
DBAccess.h:288:33: error: invalid use of non-static member function
InOut_Schedular_Settings info; //Creating list object "info"
                             ^
DBAccess.h:289:4: error: ‘info’ was not declared in this scope
info.inout_ID = A;
^
DBAccess.h:295:34: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘InOut_Schedular_Settings_list’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
InOut_Schedular_Settings_list.push_back(info);
```

I know, I have to provide typename, and also declare template<>. But unfortunately I am unable to get it right. I would highly appreciate if you could help. Thank you.

Note: I am aware that defining a function in .h file itself is bad practice. I will make another .cpp file later.

Comment: `InOut_Schedular_Settings` is a *function* and not a type. `std::list` expects a type (as do all containers). Same with the `info` variable declaration, you should provide a *type* and not a function. Either rename the structure, or rename the function.

Comment: The name of the struct `InOut_Schedular_Settings` is the same as the member function `InOut_Schedular_Settings`. So, this leads to the situation, described by @JoachimPileborg

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I totally agree with you.

Comment: @KirilKirov yes I noticed that too after posting the question. I agree with you too. I feel so stupid and embarrassed that was really very silly.

Comment: @K.K - take it easy, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I really feel stupid to post the answer of my own question. The mistake I made was really silly.

If you notice function -

```
const char* InOut_Schedular_Settings
```

has the same name as my list name:

```
231    list<InOut_Schedular_Settings>
238    list<InOut_Schedular_Settings> InOut_Schedular_Settings_list;
```

All I had to do is change the function name of:

```
const char* InOut_Schedular_Settings
```

**to** (something else)

```
const char* InOut_Schedular_Settings1
```

Sorry for being so impatient.